# Как обеспечить защиту некоторых REST запросов с помощью второго фактора аутентификации?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Имеется ресурс *сервисА* (REST сервис) и к нему обращается *сервисБ*.

*СервисА* защищен OAuth. Помимо этого необходимо, чтобы некоторые запросы были защищены с помощью OTP (one time password), которые приходят по смс.

К примеру: идет обращение на `GET /api/user` и нужно, чтобы *сервисА* не сразу отдал *JSON*, а сначала выслал СМС с кодом и затем проверил правильность кода.

Как правильно организовать такую защиту Rest сервиса?

Используется *Spring*.

Comment: Сделайте отдельный эндпоинт для получения OTP, по нужным не пускайте без соответствующего заголовка.

Comment: Есть необходимость, чтобы другие сервисы использующие сервисА не знали этот код.

Comment: Они и не будут, он же будет отправляться на телефон пользователя.

Comment: Как вариант написать интерсептор обработчик аутентификовавшегося пользователя